# Uploading multiple txt files (matrices) for network analysis on bipartite package (R)

Tags: r, network-programming, bipartite

I'm pretty new to R programming and I need to load 94 interaction network matrices to R and analyze them using the bipartite package. I'm sure there is a way I can load them simultaneously using a single code, but I don't know how! I've tried loading them using :

```
webs <- list.files()
```

So I list all the files from my working directory
but then I can't read them as matrices like I need to so I can analyze them using bipartite... I can only see the file name. When I try to visualize them like that:

```
visweb(webs$Aleixo_et_al_2013_a)
```

The following error comes up:

```
Error in webs$Aleixo_et_al_2013_a : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Since I'm new to R and programming in general, I have no idea what to do...

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You should know that `webs` is a character vector (return value of `list.files`)

> A character vector containing the names of the files in the specified
> directories (empty if there were no files). If a path does not exist
> or is not a directory or is unreadable it is skipped.

Thus `webs$Aleixo_et_al_2013_a` is not a valid if you want to access the entry `Aleixo_et_al_2013_a` from vector `webs`. I guess you can try `"Aleixo_et_al_2013_a"` instead.

Comment: Thank you :) unfortunately, when I tried `visweb("Aleixo_et_al_2013")` I got this error message: `Error in as.matrix(web) : object 'Aleixo_et_al_2013_a' not found`